# Meteor Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, email-verification

I'm using Angular Meteor.

I want the user to validate his email via `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail ()`
(Which sends a URL with a token to the click user)
I have already captured the token, and can see it in a `console.log()`

My problem is that in `onEmailVerificationLink` is not running even though I'm passing the token parameter.
This can be checked because it is not printing to the `console.log()`

Next my code in client

```
my-app\imports\ui\components\verifyMail\verifyMail.html
```

.

```
class VerifyMail {
    constructor($reactive, $scope, $stateParams) {
        'ngInject';
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.token = $stateParams.token;
        this.verifyLink();
    }

    verifyLink() {
        this.$bindToContext(
            Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink((token, done) => {
                console.log('CANT PRINT THIS CONSOLE LOG');
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The email verification callback happens on the server.

Alternatively if you use collection hooks (https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks), you can do something like this:

```
Meteor.users.after.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
  if (!!modifier.$set) {
    //check if the email was verified
    if (modifier.$set['emails.$.verified'] === true) {
      //do something
    }
  }
});
```